# Jquery Webservice in ASP.NET

Tags: ajax, web-services, url

I am working with ASP.NET 4.0 framework. In one web page, I have to call web service using Jquery as

```
     var serviceurl = 'http://www.websitename.com/webservicename';
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceurl + 'WebServiceName',
                data: "{'Parameters': '" + parameter+ "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    ShowAfterSuccess(msg);
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
```

It works fine, if i mention url as "http://www.websiteName.com" but when i put URL as "websitename.com" it doent call webservice. 
but it works well only in Google Chrome with "websiteName.com" I dont knw what is the issue with that....whether there is problem in my webservice calling or in URL..

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that you are not violating the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The best way to ensure this is to use relative urls:

```
var serviceurl = '/webservicename';
```

You must ensure that the domain hosting this javascript matches exactly the domain that you are sending your AJAX call to (including the protocol).